# PHP read 30k lines file

Tags: php

I want to read a big tab-separated-file with 30k lines. Then I'm going to split up the line but I get a max_execution_timeout even with max_execution_time 90 it timeouts...

The Lines don't have much content and I think 30k lines should be possible? Do you have an Idea?

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgets($handle);

    $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
    $line_id = $parts[0];
    echo $line_id;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if it works at all? Have you checked error messages, tried it with a smaller file, etc?

Comment: It’s tab-separated - and yet you split it at _any_ whitespace? Do this _right_ - use `fgetcsv`

Comment: your file is csv type?

Comment: As a note on style you're better off using fgetcsv() for parsing something that conforms to CSV standards than preg_split().  If the delimiter is not actually a comma you can specify what to use instead.  As for your problem, the max timeout usually doesn't apply to scripts run from the commandline.  If your script is expecting to process 30k lines then it's not something you should be running inside a web browser.

Comment: Your acceptance record is quite questionable and given not even commenting under possible solutions for your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things, **[max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)** and **[memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)** in PHP. Additionally you can try to read the file by chunks.

> **memory_limit**: This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.
>
> **max_execution_time** This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

Try this approach, here you are not reading the entire file in memory. The max memory needed to run this depends on the longest line in the input.

```
$handle = fopen("/tmp/uploadfile.txt", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        // your data processing here
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```